# Login using Facebook not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I just implemented the code for user to let him login using Facebook.
In Login View , when he clicks on button saying "Login with Facebook", it shows error like:

> View [auth.redirect] not found

By the way, my **Home View** is not on root directory but inside auth folder. I don't know why it's looking for View as redirect is just a function defined in my controller.

Route.php

```
<?php

Route::group([ 'middleware' => ['web']], function(){

      Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('auth.home');
      })->name('home');

//Facebook Login
Route::get('/redirect', 'SocialAuthFacebookController@redirect');
Route::get('/callback', 'SocialAuthFacebookController@callback');

});
```

SocialAuthFacebookController.php

```
<?php
class SocialAuthFacebookController extends Controller
{
    public function redirect()
    {
        return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
    }

 public function callback(SocialFacebookAccountService $service)
 {
     $user = $service->createOrGetUser(Socialite::driver('facebook')->user());
     auth()->login($user);
     return redirect()->to('/home');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Full description how to login facebook and laravel:**

1. Install fresh laravel
2. Create Database and connect
3. Add fb_id in users migration file
4. Run migrate command
5. Create Laravel authentication
6. composer require laravel/socialite
7. Open config/app.php, register socialite plugin in providers and aliases array

   ```
    'providers' => [
        .........
        .........
        Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class,
    ],
     'aliases' => [
       .........
       .........
      'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
   ],
   ```
8. Create Facebook App. Then add client_id and client_secret in the config/services.php like bellow.

App create link: https://developers.facebook.com/apps

```
   return [
         ....
        'facebook' => [
        'client_id' => 'Facebook app id',
        'client_secret' => 'Facebook add secret',
        'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback',
       ],
    ]
```

9. Create route in web.php

   ```
   Route::get('auth/facebook', [SocialController::class, 'facebookRedirect']);
   Route::get('auth/facebook/callback', [SocialController::class, 'loginWithFacebook']);
   ```
10. In Controller

    ```
        namespace App\Http\Controllers;
        use Illuminate\Http\Request;    
        use App\Models\User;
        use Validator;
        use Socialite;
        use Auth;


    class SocialController extends Controller
     {

      public function facebookRedirect()
      {
          return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
      }

      public function loginWithFacebook(){
        $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->stateless()->user();
        $finduser = User::where('fb_id', $user->id)->first();

        if($finduser){
            Auth::login($finduser);
            return redirect('/user-profile');
        }else{
            $newUser = new User();
            $newUser->name      = $user->name;
            $newUser->email     = $user->email;
            $newUser->fb_id     = $user->id;
            $newUser->password  = bcrypt('12345678');
            $newUser->save();
            Auth::login($newUser);
            return redirect('/user-profile');
          }
       }
    }
    ```
11. Add facebook login button in login page

    ```
     <a class="btn" href="{{ url('auth/facebook') }}">Login with Facebook</a>
    ```
12. Start php artisan serve and test

**Video Description:** https://youtu.be/AaFxO2l0N8k

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a critical part which is to link Users with their social ID's.

Here is a great tutorial: https://medium.com/@confidenceiyke/laravel-5-8-facebook-socialite-authentication-8863b9a43f11

That tutorial will guide you through setting up the Facebook app as well.

Comment: That won't work, you're missing the function. Read the tutorial all the way through.

Comment: Hi !
i just followed the above tutorial and replaced my code with his code. 
Still same error "View [auth.redirect] not found." ?????
By the way, My home View is not on root directory, it's under auth folder. 

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it myself. 
I' m using Laravel version 6.

All you need to make 3 below changes:

Change

```
FACEBOOK_REDIRECT=http://localhost:8000/callback
```

to

```
FACEBOOK_REDIRECT=http://localhost:8000/facebook/callback
```

Then Change,

```
Route::get('/redirect', 'SocialAuthFacebookController@redirect');
Route::get('/callback', 'SocialAuthFacebookController@callback');
```

to

```
Route::get('/facebook/redirect', 'SocialAuthFacebookController@redirect');
Route::get('/facebook/callback', 'SocialAuthFacebookController@callback');
```

Finally in Login View
Change

```
<a href="{{url('/redirect')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</a>
```

to

```
<a href="{{url('/facebook/redirect')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</a>
```

Reference link: https://desertebs.com/laravel/laravel-facebook-login-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

**Use it and it will hepl you to solve your problem**

```
   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

- ```
  public function handleFacebookLogin(Request $request){

   $facebookUser = Http::get("https://graph.facebook.com/me? fields=id,name,email&access_token=$request->access_token")->json(); // Will return id, name and email (if your facebook registered with an email)

   if(empty($facebookUser['email']))
       return response()->json(['error' => "Your Facebook account doesn\'t have a registered email or the email information is missing."], 400);

    $facebookUserId = $facebookUser['id'];
    $profilePhoto = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/$facebookUserId/picture?type=normal";

  }
  ```
- It has solved my problem. Thank you.